# Restore a ROM Back-up

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, rom, restore

I am going to try out CyanogenMod tonight on my phone. Before I do that, however, I am curious about one thing. I performed a NANDROID backup, per instructions that I received on this site (thank you to Bryan), as well as a Titanium Backup of all my applications and data. What I am confused about is - say I really screw something up during the CyanogenMod process? How would I recover from that? From my own research, it appears it works something like this:

1. Made NANDROID backup. (Should be on the SD card.)
2. If something goes completely screwy, boot into Recovery mode (hold X on boot, Volume Up + Camera key).
3. Flash using the NANDROID backup off the SD card to return to a safe state.
4. Get Titanium and restore all apps.

Is it really that simple, or am I missing some aspect? (I should just do it, but I'm a bit worried about royally screwing up my phone.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really that simple. :)

And you wouldn't even have to do step 4 (because your NANDROID backup is like taking an image of your phone, that includes all installed apps and data too).

If you wanted to do a quick test, you could try installing one app, then restoring to your NANDROID backup.  When it's done, it should no longer have that one app  you installed.  And it'll also show that your backup is good.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for quelling my fears. I use my phone a lot (my primary means of internet access right now) and I would hate to really screw it up. Glad to know that there are solutions like this. Excited to check out Cyanogen tonight! :-)

Comment: +1 - I have been toying with the idea for some time and I was worried about getting my Droid X back to a working state if something went wrong.  Does ROM Manager do the same type of ROM backup?

Comment: @shambleh With ROM manager you install Clockwork Recovery.  Then inside of Rom Manager you can initiate or restore backups.  You can also do this inside of Clockwork Recovery on boot (you should always be able to get into it even if your phone gets stuck in a boot-loop or similar).